# Repetir um algoritmo se a resposta for errada em jogo adivinhação sem perder o número sorteado

Tags: python, algoritmo

Eu fiz um algoritmo em Python com a proposta de adivinhar um número conforme o usuário digite, ou seja, o jogo da adivinhação. Porém gostaria de fazer uma condição que faça ele digitar novamente, caso ele não escolher o numero desejado, não faço ideia como faço, por causa do módulo `random`.

```
import random
import time

def c():

num =(int(input("Adivinha um numero de 0 a 5: ").strip()))
numB = random.randint(0,5)
print("CARREGANDO..............................")
time.sleep(1)

if num == numB:
    print('Parabéns! Você acertou o numero\n'
          'Você é um vencedor !')
elif num > numB: # Condição do valor diferente, só uma amostra(Está errado)
    print("Valor errado") 

else:
    print("Errado! Tente de Novo")
    time.sleep(1)
    c() 
c()
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Ficar chamando a mesma função não é muito adequado, pode inclusive estourar o *stack*, embora neste caso seja altamente improvável isto ocorrer, mas acostume-se fazer certo. O melhor é fazer um laço e sair só se estiver certo. O sorteio obviamente fica fora do laço para não sortear outro número em cada tentativa, simples e fácil quando usa o mecanismo certo.

```
import random

def c():
    numB = random.randint(0, 5)
    while True:
        num = int(input("Adivinha um numero de 0 a 5: ").strip())
        if num == numB:
            print('Parabéns! Você acertou o numero\n'
                  'Você é um vencedor !')
            break
        elif num > numB:
            print("Valor errado")
        else:
            print("Errado! Tente de Novo")
c()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZOreEb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RepeatIfWrongAnswer). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/RepeatIfWrongAnswer.py).